# Play framework scala debugging in netbeans

Tags: scala, netbeans, playframework

I am able to debug scala controller in play framework using netbeans IDE but the issue is I cannot set breakpoint when I am within a loop like:

```
val strs: List[String] = txt.split("\\s+").toList
for (str <- strs) {
       if (str == "some")
        .....

}
```

When I try to set breakpoint at line " if (str == " netbeans tells me: Broken breakpoint: it is not possible to stop on this line.

Most of my code is within loops, so I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"For" expression is translated to "map":

http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/for-expressions-revisited.html#23.4

Regards